# Dynamically Instantiate a Function & Call a Method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Take this JavaScript class:

```
var Foo = function() {

    this.bar = function() {
        return 'foobar';
    };

};
```

I can instantiate this class and call it's `bar` method like this:

```
(new Foo).bar();
```

I would like to achieve the instantiation and calling of the class and it's method dynamically based of a string that represents a class and method like `Foo@bar`.

I have tries the following to achieve this but receive the error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`:

```
var action = 'Foo@bar';
var classMethod = action.split('@');

(new classMethod[0]).call(classMethod[1]);
```

Is this even possible in JavaScript or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: `(new classMethod[0])[classMethod[1]]()` a bit strange tough that you would want to do this, what actual problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I have certain classes that need to be instantiated automatically in the code and methods that need to be called without manually having to new up objects and call their methods. Your method `(new classMethod[0])[classMethod[1]]()` throws the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with eval.  But I won't show that because eval is evil.

If you are willing to create an object containing the types that can be created:

```
var Foo = function() {
    this.bar = function() {
        return 'foobar';
    };
};  
var types = {
    Foo : Foo
};

var action = 'Foo@bar';
var classMethod = action.split('@');

(new types[classMethod[0]])[classMethod[1]]();
```

The problem with your code was that `classMethod[0]` is a string.  But to use `new` you need to give it a function.
In my code I make use of javascript's `[]` operators which accesses properties of an object using a string containing the property's name.
First I use it to get the Foo property from the types object.  This is your constructor.
Then after calling the constructor, I use the `[]` operators again to get the bar property.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Foo` object

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

You can say `foo["bar"]();` to call a method called `bar` on it.

Answer (score 0):

To access constructor by names you need to have it accessible in some collection. For example:

```
var Foo = function() {
    this.bar = function() {
        return 'foobar';
    };
};

var constructors = {
  Foo: Foo,
  Bar: Bar
};

function instantiateAndInvoke(action) {
  var classMethod = action.split('@');
  var constr = constructors[classMethod[0]];
  var instance = new constr();

  return instance[classMethod[1]]();
}

// and then
var result = instantiateAndInvoke('Foo@bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

`classMethod[0]` is a string, so you can't use it as a constructor.

Assuming `Foo` is a global function,

```js
new window[classMethod[0]]()[classMethod[1]]();
```